# Xcode build error Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos

I am opening up an existing project in xcode 7.2. I'm getting the following error:

> Library not found for -lBolts
>
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: what did you do to install Bolts?

Comment: @johnelemans I didnt install bolts. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look for Bolts here;

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC

Your best approach is probably to use cocopods to install it. See the bottom of the page for installation info.

(Your error results because the library that your app needs is not available to xcode.)

Comment: i added the gem for the cocoapods and edited the pod file to specify
pod 'Bolts'.
Am i suppose to see the Bolts Framework somewhere to add to my project? because i dont see it.

Comment: i also installed the pod.

Comment: after installing the pod I think that you have to open as a workspace not your old project file. Check the cocopods docs. You should have a workspace file in the same folder where your project file is now.